# Is there a way to pause/resume a serenity-js test run to check the browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, serenity-js

In a test context, we have been setting up a mock to behave a certain way including accessing the service under test, and we want to inspect the browser mid test because it isn't working in the way we expected.

Accessing the mock url direct doesnt give us the insight we need - we want to set headless:false and inspect the browser in the test execution.

Ca we set a pause/resume so we can check what we want? Then I guess cancelling the run is the simplest next step, or maybe continuing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you right, but maybe you can use a `Wait.for(Duration.ofMinutes(60))` (see [Wait (Serenity/JS 2.x)](https://serenity-js.org/modules/protractor/class/src/screenplay/interactions/Wait.ts%7EWait.html) or [Wait (Serenity/JS 3.x)](https://github.com/serenity-js/serenity-js/blob/main/integration/web-specs/spec/screenplay/interactions/Wait.spec.ts).

Then you should have enough time to inspect your systems.

Comment: Not exactly but I guess that could be useful in some circumstances